# Make a Dynamic select case (vb)

Tags: sql, vb.net, select-case

I would like to have one of my cases be a dynamic string because in my table these values changed partially except for the beginning code "2061"
so how do I make my code do something similar to when I'm looking up in my query 
"... like '2061%'
here is my code

```
Function GetResponse(val As String) As String
        Select Case val
            Case "2061"
                Return "Opted Out"
            Case "00"
                Return ""
            Case Else
                Return "Other"
        End Select
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operator in VB.NET for this.  Here I'm selecting the first case that matches True.

```
Function GetResponse(val As String) As String
    Select Case True
        Case val Like "2061*"
            Return "Opted Out"
        Case val = "00"
            Return ""
        Case Else
            Return "Other"
    End Select
End Function
```

In C# you would use an if statement to get the same functionality:

```
string GetResponse(string value)
{
    if (value.StartsWith("2061"))
        return "Opted Out";
    else if (value == "00")
        return "";
    else
        return "Other";
}
```

And in F#:

```
let GetResponse (value:string) =
    match value with
    | x when x.StartsWith("2061") -> "Opted Out"
    | "00" -> ""
    | _ -> "Other"
```

Note, I recommend using more descriptive function and variable names than this, but I don't know what context this code is in.  "GetResponse" is vague, and doesn't indicate what the return values might mean.  You might want to rename it as "GetUserOptedOutStatus" or something similar.